*Issue with Marker Placement on Imported .fbx Objects in Unity
I'm currently working on a Unity project where I need to place markers on objects imported from *.fbx files. The selection of these objects works fine, but when I try to place a marker, the marker doesn't appear on the object. This issue only occurs with objects imported from *.fbx files. I've ensured that the colliders are properly set up and have tested various scripts and settings, but the problem persists. The marker placement works correctly on basic Unity objects like cubes but not on the imported models.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest a solution?
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can suggest a solution?

Some screenshots with the problem would be more explanatory

I have successfully tested placing the marker at the desired position in the Unity Editor, but when I tested it on HoloLens, the marker did not appear

Can you collect application logs, there's probably some Unity log about incompatible materials. Those usually render as transparent

This is log from debuging in Visual Studio:
Processing and Loading: The log shows that numerous system libraries such as ntdll.dll, KernelBase.dll, ucrtbase.dll, and others were successfully loaded with debug symbols available. This indicates that the application is running with all necessary components.
Exceptions and Access Denied Errors: Several exceptions were thrown, such as Element not found and Access is denied, suggesting that the application attempted to access elements or resources that were unavailable or unauthorized.

I bet that's not the full log from the device, just a slice of messages from Visual Studio debugger itself. I'm not a hololens user, maybe try to follow this question

yes, that is not a complete log of debug from visual studio, if I copy all in this message it is not enough, I am a new member in this forum, I have not explored the share document or screenshot features
